# Transforming some postgres table

Tags: postgresql

[image]

I have some data table like the above left table and it is a snippet, so there are a lot more unique IDs.
I would like to write a postgres code to transform the table to something like the right.

Comment: Look into the `lag` windowing function

Comment: I tried something like...
lag(date)over(partition by id order by ...) as 

can't get it to work and not very familiar with this

Comment: I guess you'll need to nest two queries (or use a CTE), the first to remove the rows where the status doesn't change, the second to calculate the days to the next status change